# AngularJs CRUD operations remove unwanted code

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new and using angularjs in my project.
For example I am using the bellow operations.

```
1. Create
2. View
3. Edit
4. List
```

In this four operations I am using 4 html page.

I understand the LIST operation need one html page.
So Now I trying to reduce the Add/View/Edit html pages into single page.

Here I didn't attached my html and js code but I need to Idea for how to do simply the codes.

I trying: 
1. One page html display the all records(list).
2. Add/Edit/View - all operations should be single html page.

Can anyone the suggest the best way or demo.

Comment: Viewing and editing are quite different. You shouldn't use the same template for both. Edit and Create can sometimes use the same template. Just try it, ans ask a concrete question when you have a concrete problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same html for create & edit.

To use the same html for view, then try having mode as extra parameter.

Modes: Create, Edit and View.

You can disable entire html in 'view' mode.

Answer (score 0):

I keep them same template for create and edit to avoid updating forms at two places whenever requirement changes.

Module can have routes as defined:

```
.state('home.contentFeeds', {
          abstract: true,
          url: '/content-feeds',
          template: '<div ui-view></div>',
          controller: function () {
          }
        })
        .state('home.contentFeeds.list', {
          url: '/list?status&published',
          templateUrl: 'app/administrator/content-feeds/list/list-content-feeds.html',
          controller: 'ListContentFeedsController'
        })
        .state('home.contentFeeds.upsert', {
          url: '/upsert/:contentFeedId',
          templateUrl: 'app/administrator/content-feeds/upsert/upsert-content-feed.html',
          controller: 'UpsertContentFeedController'
        })
        .state('home.contentFeeds.view', {
          url: '/view/:contentFeedId',
          templateUrl: 'app/administrator/content-feeds/view/view-content-feed.html',
          controller: 'ViewContentFeedController'
        })
```

I prefer naming the route, html view and controller as containing the word **upsert** (derived from **up**date and in**sert** word).

There can be chances that the edit form have fewer fields than the create form and in those cases you can hide fields using `ng-show`. You'll also need to use `ng-required` to opt out fields so that they are not validated.

Presence of id passed to the route can be checked if it is a new/edit form.

View forms should be kept separate because that displays information without needing heavy markup of html input controls.